# Afterevent event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, listener

I will take keydown event listener as an example.

One can use

```
$('#my-input').keydown(function(){
  //actions goes here
});
```

I understand that the above event listener runs when it encounters a keydown event.

I need an "afterkeydown event" like so:

```
$('#my-input').afterkeydown(function(){
  //actions after keydown listener has occured
});
```

I however do not want to use a keyup event listener nor any kind of timer to achieve this 
because a keyup event listener does not get trigger when a key is repeatedly held and timers are slow.

Is a "callback event listener" on keydown possible under these limitations, if so, can it be generalized to all Jquery event listeners? Meaning, is it possible to create an 'afterclick', 'afterdrop', 'afterclick', ... event listener for Jquery?

Comment: What's the point of afterclick, afterdrop, etc...?  I see no reason.

Comment: Supposed you are trying to create a plug-in that auto corrects user input in a textarea.

Comment: keyup? Can you describe what you want to do?

Comment: You could make your custom events and trigger them inside the events you want them to happen. And for 'when a key is repeatedly held' you could use `keypress`.

Comment: i think it can be achieve if you trigger events like that in settimeout().

Comment: Even if I create a custom event and it was trigger inside the keydown event listener, the triggering of a custom event will still occur in the duration of the keydown listener and not after the keydown listener. I don't want to use keypress because of compatibility issues.

Comment: maverickosama92, I do not want to use timers.

Answer (score 0):

Since it sounds like what you're really trying to do is to get notified anytime a textarea has been changed, here's some code I've used for that specific issue.  It will call your callback anytime the content has been changed via keyboard, drag/drop, mouse, etc...

```
(function($) {

    var isIE = false;
    // conditional compilation which tells us if this is IE
    /*@cc_on
    isIE = true;
    @*/

    // Events to monitor if 'input' event is not supported
    // The boolean value is whether we have to 
    // re-check after the event with a setTimeout()
    var events = [
        "keyup", false,
        "blur", false,
        "focus", false,
        "drop", true,
        "change", false,
        "input", false,
        "textInput", false,
        "paste", true,
        "cut", true,
        "copy", true,
        "contextmenu", true
    ];
    // Test if the input event is supported
    // It's too buggy in IE so we never rely on it in IE
    if (!isIE) {
        var el = document.createElement("input");
        var gotInput = ("oninput" in el);
        if  (!gotInput) {
            el.setAttribute("oninput", 'return;');
            gotInput = typeof el["oninput"] == 'function';
        }
        el = null;
        // if 'input' event is supported, then use a smaller
        // set of events
        if (gotInput) {
            events = [
                "input", false,
                "textInput", false
            ];
        }
    }

    $.fn.userChange = function(fn, data) {
        function checkNotify(e, delay) {
            var self = this;
            var this$ = $(this);

            if (this.value !== this$.data("priorValue")) {
                this$.data("priorValue", this.value);
                fn.call(this, e, data);
            } else if (delay) {
                // The actual data change happens aftersome events
                // so we queue a check for after
                // We need a copy of e for setTimeout() because the real e
                // may be overwritten before the setTimeout() fires
                var eCopy = $.extend({}, e);
                setTimeout(function() {checkNotify.call(self, eCopy, false)}, 1);
            }
        }

        // hook up event handlers for each item in this jQuery object
        // and remember initial value
        this.each(function() {
            var this$ = $(this).data("priorValue", this.value);
            for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i+=2) {
                (function(i) {
                    this$.on(events[i], function(e) {
                        checkNotify.call(this, e, events[i+1]);
                    });
                })(i);
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Usage is:

```
 $("#whatever").userChange(yourCallbackFn, optionalData);
```

Comment: I am more interested in finding an afterevent listener than something that detects user input. Also, this solution has a timer, which is not what I want.

Comment: @wklhuey - there is no such thing as an afterevent listener so you would be better off looking for a solution to your actual problem (which is what I tried to provide).  A timer is the only way to trigger an event AFTER the event listener is processed by other code which is often what you want when you want keyboard handlers to have already done their work.